# Why am I getting broken access to layouts.app (for lavravel app) on heroku hosting but not on localhost?

Tags: laravel, heroku, cloud, hosting

I am a student and have created my first Laravel App (A blog app). I have a layout/master view created named app.blade.php in resources/views/layouts folder.

I am using laravel 5.6.

It works perfectly on localhost but not on heroku hosting.

Here is my project structure

[image]

Here is my code in home.blade.php

[image]

Heroku hosting error screen below

[image]

Localhost view

[image]

clueless about this problem. I need your support.

**EDIT**

I solved the problem. I am on a windows system while hosting on a linux platform. So my sweet innocent windows was not updating the "Layouts" on server with "layouts".

But I am with another problem

[image]

Regards,
Arpan

but loading /login /register correctly

[image]

Now this doesn't end here,

when I type /login with the url it gives me
[image]

Now I observe that when i click the link it shows me Not secure connection and displays properly but when typing there is https but not displayed correctly.

Please help me analyse and figure out the issue.

**Github repo link** : https://github.com/ArpanKIIT2017/blog4b/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its because the app was unable to find the file. But everything looks good. can you check if the file exists on remote server. 
what are you using to push the files to remote server?.

try running

```
php artisan view:clear
```

on both local and heroku

Comment: I am using github repo. And I pushed it properly.

Comment: are you sure the file exists on the remote server?

Comment: Anyways I solved the problem from your hint. Made a ls request to the server to check files found that the folder is Layouts and not layouts. Although i changed it to layouts in local it wasn't updated to repo since I am working on a windows machine. Development on windows really sucks.

Comment: Check for errors in the web browser (preferably Chrome) console, mention them if any.

Answer (score 0):

Actually Heroku doesn't support SSL in free tier. So https actually won't work.

Finnaly migrated my app to postgre sql.

Problem mainly was due to the uppercase and lowercase representation of "Layouts".

So my app is Up and Running only with one problem that is heroku doesn't support file uploads. It is not storing any file upload. Searching solution for that but not related to this post.

Thank You